# Error when I'm installing parse frameworks: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cocoapods

I tried to install the frameworks of Parse, but even when I installed it manually, and also when I installed it through Cocoapods (terminal) that gave me the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install bolts frameworks also.
add this line to your pod file.

pod 'Bolts'

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS

Comment: I did it, and i still have the same erorr :(

Comment: do you have any bolts library in the link with library phase or there is a path is framework search path which points to it

Comment: Because you are saying yo have installed it manually as well , There will be two bolts frameworks i guess in the project one i the main Xcode project and other in the pods. If it exist in both delete from the main Xcode project  and see if error remains. if remains it means it is linked in the build phase-> link with library.